# Why should I transpose coefficient vector in linear regression?

Tags: regression, linear-model, state-space-models

I was reading a basic state-space model that looks like this (here, $\mathbf X$ is a vector of predictor variables):
$$
\begin{align}
&(1) \quad y_t = \mu_t + \tau_t + \lambda_t + \epsilon_t, \epsilon_t \sim N(0,V_{\epsilon})\\
&(2) \quad \mu_{t+1} = \mu_t + \xi_t, \xi_t \sim N(0,W_{\xi})\\
&(3) \quad \tau_{t+1} = \sum_{s=0}^{50}\tau_{t-s}+u_t, u_t \sim N(0, W_{u})\\
&(4) \quad \lambda_t = \beta^T\mathbf{X}_t
\end{align}
$$
My question is: Why is the coefficient vector transposed in the regression component? This seems odd to me. Typically you would see the transpose is made on the data matrix, like here in linear regression:
$$
y = \beta\mathbf{X}^T + \epsilon
$$
or this:
$$
y = \mathbf{X}\beta + \epsilon
$$
Could anybody please explain?

Answer (score 1):

I don't agree with the notation, but don't get lost in the weeds because I think you can figure out the important bits. Statisticians can get a little loose with their matrix algebra, especially that a matrix with one row or one column is treated like a vector. In several places in the display you posted, I think the author would agree $y + y^T = 2y$.

I am used to seeing the expression for the fitted value as $\hat{y} = X^T \beta$, and consequently $y = \hat{y} + \epsilon$.. The $\beta$ as a matrix is usually thought of as a $p \times 1$ matrix, that's what you get from solving $\hat{\beta} = (X^TX)^{-1}X^T Y$ where $X$ is a $n \times p$ matrix of regressors (with or without an intercept term as a column). Here the $y$ is also thought of as a $n \times 1$ matrix.

Comment: The real issue comes down to showing that definition (4), which involves the design matrix $X,$ is consistent with the $y=\beta X^\prime + \cdots$ formulation.  There does not appear to be any "looseness" in this notation.

Comment: @whuber could you please elaborate a little bit more? So do you mean if X is defined as is (a vector of predictor variables), it makes sense to transpose the coefficient vector? (perhaps to match the number of rows and columns to allow multiplication?)

Comment: Assuming $\lambda_t$ in (4) is a scalar, the rules of matrix multiplication imply $\beta$ and $X_t$ must be column vectors with as many components as there are predictors.  Consequently, only the second expression $y=X\beta+\cdots$ makes any sense, and that in turn tells us $X_t$ must be the transpose of row $t$ in matrix $X.$  In other words, one works through material like this by taking it on its own terms, rather than approaching it from a preferred perspective.  Conventions vary, but most writers will use vectors and matrices consistently within a document.

Comment: @whuber this is a state space model, so $X_t$ is the design matrix $X$ of dimension $n \times p$ at time $t$, not transposed. I think (thought) OP's confusion was that the fitted value is expressed as $\beta^T X$ which is a $1 \times n$ vector, whereas $X^T \beta$ would be $n \times 1$.

Comment: @AdamO actually, it says that Xt is a vector of predictor variables (which I am assuming the dimension is n x 1, n as in the number of variables). I think β should also be a n x 1 vector - that is the only way β transpose would make sense to me...

Comment: @whuber you're right, λt in (4) is a scalar.

Comment: I believe, Kang, that the source consistently uses "vector" to mean a *column vector.*  At any rate, its notation conforms to such a convention.  This agrees with @Adam's comment: the rows of the design matrix $X$ are indexed by $t$ (just as $Y$ is) and, because they are *row vectors,* they will be expressed as the *transposes* of the column vectors $X_t.$  That is, you may visualize $X$ as a stack of rows $X_1^\prime,$ $X_2^\prime,$ down to $X_n^\prime.$

Comment: @whuber again I may have a different interpretation. I think another possibility here is that $\mathbf{X}_t$ represents a whole design matrix at time $t$, i.e. each covariate is evaluated at time $t$. But I can see how the $t$ subscript can indicate a row subset. producing a single vector. Anyway, the ultimate source is the paper or text that this came from, and if it's not clear, not a bad idea to shoot an innocuous note to the author that the notation could do with some sprucing up.

Comment: @AdamO Agreed on all points.  Thank you for those clarifications.